I can't share a note from an app to another app

private fun shareNote(title: String, description: String, imageUriList: MutableList<String>) {
    val shareIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title)
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "$title\n\n$description")
        type = if (imageUriList.isNotEmpty()) "image/*" else "text/plain"
        if (imageUriList.isNotEmpty()) {
            val uriList = ArrayList<Uri>()
            imageUriList.forEach { uriString ->
                val uri = Uri.parse(uriString) // Adjust if these URIs are not parsed correctly
                uriList.add(uri)
            }
            putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriList)
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        }
    }
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Note"))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        requireContext().showToastShort("Sharing failed")
    }
}

I want to share a note containing text and pictures like this, but when I select the application I will share it with, the application does not open.
I checked the listings and they are all as they should be
AndroidManifest.xml
<provider
            android:authorities="com.notes.purenoteit.fileprovider"
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            >
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>

file_paths.xml
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>

images uri
content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw/%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FAndroid%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2FWhatsApp%20Images%2FIMG-20241125-WA0001.jpg

Correction: If I add a picture and share it without closing the application, it can be shared successfully, but if I say share after closing the application, this time I cannot share it.

Did you set up a file provider? See: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send

I implemented this but it still failed. Can you send me a working code?

Your code seems mostly correct for sharing both text and images using an Intent.
If you are using FileProvider, ensure your AndroidManifest.xml and res/xml/file_paths.xml are properly configured:
Manifest snippet:
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"> // grant URI permission 
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>

res/xml/file_paths.xml snippet:
 <paths>
    <external-path name="shared_images" path="Pictures/" />
</paths>

I have refined version of your method with improved handling for the mentioned issue:
private fun shareNote(title: String, description: String, imageUriList: MutableList<String>) {
        val shareIntent = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE
            type = if (imageUriList.isNotEmpty()) "image/*" else "text/plain"
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title)
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "$title\n\n$description")

            if (imageUriList.isNotEmpty()) {
                val uriList = ArrayList<Uri>()
                imageUriList.forEach { uriString ->
                    val uri = Uri.parse(uriString) // Adjust if these URIs are not parsed correctly
                    uriList.add(uri)
                }
                putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriList)
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            }
        }
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Note"))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Toast.makeText(context, "No app available to share the note.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }


I did it this way, but when I try to open the application I will share, the application does not open and no error message appears on the screen.

OHh is this so worried, can you please share more details in code, I can help you out

Actually, I gave all the information with the code.
Now, if I try to share it when I add the first image, I can share it without any problems. If I close the application and open it again and say share again, this time the application I will share does not open.

fun dialPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: String) {
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL).apply {
    data = Uri.parse("tel:$phoneNumber")
}
if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivity(intent)
}

}
Use fun like this.

That would launch an app that can dial a phone number.  It has nothing to do with an app to display pictures and text.  Nor would resolveActivity here be appropriate, as they're looking for an app that can open specific MIME types, not a specific URL.
